# Pass results from loop into a form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my ruby on rails application, I am trying to take results from an API (OMDBapi) call (response in JSON) and then display the results in a view. This is working as expected. In this case its a list of movie titles, the year it was made and the omdbID. 
I am try to take the omdbID value from the result and place that into a button that will call another method (which does a different API call to OMDB) to provide the rating of that specific movie that the user selected.

At the moment I am unable to get the button to provide any action, even though I believe I have my route configured correctly. Below is a part of my view. The results show correctly, and I get a button next to each result. But the button does nothing.

```
    <% @responsealltitles.each do |result| %>
    <td><%= result["Title"] %> </td>
    <td><%= result["Year"] %></td>
    <td><%= result["imdbID"] %></td>

    <td><%= submit_tag("Search for Rating") %> 
    <%= label_tag(:find_rating, "Show Movie Rating") %>
    <%= form_tag( "findrating", method: "post") do %></td>
```

Here is my routes entry

```
    match 'findrating', to: 'info#inforated', via: [:get, :post]
```

Any thoughts what is wrong here? I am a beginner at coding, and at ruby.

Comment: are you wrapping the submit tag in a form? by the way, the ruby convention is to use underscores for readability, i.e. `@response_all_titles`

Comment: Hi Max. Could you clarify what you mean by wrapping it in a form? How would I do that?

Comment: well, a 'submit' input needs to be in a `<form>` tag. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: No, I am not wrapping it in a form. I have not done so with any other views that I have created to date. All my other submit buttons work based on the functionality that I have created without using a form.

Comment: . The `form_tag ... do ... end` block is creating a form tag, but this "Search for Rating" tag is not wrapped in one.